# Filter polars DataFrame given an external condition

Tags: python, python-polars

Is there a way to filter a polars df given an external variable?
I currently do it this way:

```
_df = (_df.with_columns(...)...)
_variable = 1
if _variable==1:
    _df = _df.filter(pl.col("date")=="2020-02-01")
else:
    _df = _df.filter(pl.col("seller")="Markets")
```

Is there a way to filter this way inside the first piece of code? like:

```
_variable = 1
_df = (_df
       .with_columns(...)
       .filter(pl.col("date")=="2020-02-01") if _variable==1 else 
       .filter(pl.col("seller")="Markets")
       .sort(...)
       ...)
```

I ask this because I read that polars works better if you do everything at once instead of working as if it was a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an implicit question here which is, is it better to chain afilter operation rather than set a df after a `with_columns`? Not really.

> I read that polars works better if you do everything at once instead of working as if it was a pandas dataframe

It's true that in polars we don't want to do something like this

```
df = df.with_columns(c=pl.col('a') + pl.col('b'))
df = df.with_columns(d=pl.col('a') * pl.col('b'))
```

We just want to do

```
df = df.with_columns(
         c=pl.col('a') + pl.col('b'),
         d=pl.col('a') * pl.col('b')
      )
```

The reason is that every expression that you give it at once, it'll run in parallel. If you chain multiple `select` or `with_columns` you're making it do each of those one after another rather than in parallel.

Bringing this back to the filter question, there's not a penalty for doing things like

```
_df = (_df.with_columns(...)...)
_variable = 1
if _variable==1:
    _df = _df.filter(pl.col("date")=="2020-02-01")
else:
    _df = _df.filter(pl.col("seller")="Markets")
```

instead of doing all the operations in a single chain which would look like this if you wanted to do it this way anyway

```
_variable = 1
_df = (_df
       .with_columns(...)
       .filter((pl.col("date")=="2020-02-01") if _variable==1 else 
               (pl.col("seller")=="Markets"))
       .sort(...)
       ...)
```

The trick is that you do it inside the filter, just make sure to put your filter expressions in parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Polars expressions are "objects".

```py
type(pl.col("foo") == "bar")
```

```py
<polars.expr.expr.Expr at 0x12e01b040>
```

They can be used outside of `.select()`, `.with_columns()`  and stored in variables like any other Python object.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 5, 10], "B": [6, 4, 3]})

variable = 1

if variable == 1:
   expr = pl.col("A") > 5 
else:
   expr = pl.col("B") < 5

expr.meta.serialize()
```

[`.meta.serialize()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.meta.serialize.html) is one way to inspect them.

```py
'{"BinaryExpr":{"left":{"Column":"A"},"op":"Gt","right":{"Literal":{"Int32":5}}}}'
```

```py
df.filter(expr)
```

```py
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 10  ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
```